# Differences between`[.]` vs `.` in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

The following expressions are not the same: `/[.]*/` and `/.*/`. Why is that, and how exactly are they different? What is the interaction between the `[]` and special characters in regular expressions?

Thank you.

Comment: BTW, the "proper" way to escape special characters is with the backslash, so `/[.]*/` would be `/\.*/`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The dot `.` is normally a wildcard, matching any character. Within a character class (the `[]`) however, it is treated as a literal and only matches a dot.

Comment: More precisely, `.` usually matches any character except newlines.

Answer (score 8):

- `.*` literally means "Match zero or more of *any* character", wherein the `.` acts as a wildcard.
- `[.]*` literally means "Match zero or more dot `.` characters", wherein the `.` enclosed in a character class `[]` is matched literally.